# Null after mongo array projection in aggregation in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

This is my last stage in Mongo:

```
{
  name: 1,
  items: "$activeItems",
  tables: {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$activeTables",
      "as": "table",
      "in": {
        "tableName": "$$table.tableName",
        "tableId": "$$table.tableId"
```

I have written it this way in Spring data:

```
final var projectStage = Aggregation.project()
        .andInclude("name")
        .andExpression("$activeItems").as("items")
        .and(VariableOperators.Map.itemsOf("$activeTables").as("table")
                .andApply(doc -> {
                    Document document = new Document();
                    document.append("tableName", "$$table.tableName");
                    document.append("tableId", "$$table.tableId");
                    return document;
                }))
        .as("tables");

    final var result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Something.class, SomethingDto.class);
```

Something entity is defined as

```
@Document(collection = "#{@mongoProperties.getSomethingCollectionName()}")
@TypeAlias("something")
public class Something{ 
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<SomethingElseIdDto> somethingElse;
    private List<Long> tables;
}
```

DTOs are plain POJO:

```
public class SomethingDto {
    String name;
    List<ItemDto> items;
    List<TableDto> tables;
}

@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ItemDto {
    Long itemId;
    String itemName;
```

When running a spring boot app, I get complete data from the REST endpoint including `items` and `tables` arrays. But an integration test sees both arrays `tables` and `items` as empty. I verified in Compass that they are computed in Mongo even in the test collection.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "integration-test"})
class DbServiceTest {
```

Sample data:

```
{
    "name": "XYZ",
    "items": [
        {
            "itemId": 123,
            "itemName": "A",
        },
    "tables": [
        {
            "tableId": 456,
            "tableName": "Q",
        },
```

This is weird. Same code has different results depending on spring profile.

Comment: Can you please share a couple of sample data?

Comment: I can do, once I get to my computer. It is really weird that the code works perfectly. Then I created a unit test to cover edge cases and it behaves differently. I have no idea why it doesn't initialize these object array properties in the test score.

Comment: My fault. I need to generate the aggregation dynamically because I use a different collection name in the test. I will keep the question because the code may be helpful to other people in future. It took me some time to construct such aggregation.

Comment: @LeosLiterak if you found the solution yourself, I think you can answer your own question and close it. It may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is that the colletions must be dynamically computed too:

```
final var resolvedStage = Aggregation.lookup(mongoProperties.getSomethingCollectionName()(),
            "something.id", "id", "items");
```